# Storing Information Online That Can Be Retrieved From An Android Application

Tags: java, android, cloud, storage

I am creating a basic Android application at the moment where I am populating text views with information from an Arraylist, but I intend on retrieving information from an online storage as the ultimate goal. The information is quite small just a name, description and age. I was wondering is there any simple types of storage where I can store like 20-50 lines of example data and then retrieve to populate textviews. Any suggestions would be great. I looked into stuff such as parse but I am just curious if there is anything more smaller as the data set I am storing is quite small.

Cheers.

Comment: Hi, take a look at Firebase and its Realtime Database: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ :)

Comment: Hey, at the moment this seems exactly what I need. I am guessing I am able to store an object of my data types on this, right?

Comment: That's right :) Firebase operates with JSON structure. You can simply convert your objects into JSON using Gson or any other library and add it to Firebase JSON structure in one request. You also is able to add/edit/remove fields of your objects separately.

Answer (score 0):

You may look into "Google DataStore"